# wscat connection unexpected server response: 403

Tags: powershell, alpaca, wscat

I'm new to alpaca trading. Ran wscat -c wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream to connect and got error 403. Looks like an authorization thing.

I tried using wscat --auth <user: pass> but got the error The '<' operator is reserved for future use. Please lmk what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `--auth <username:password>` in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat) symbolizes that `<username:password>` is a _placeholder_ for an actual username-password pair, such as `jdoe:somepass` (if this pairs contains special characters, enclose it in `'...'`)

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Check your URLs: https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-references/market-data-api/stock-pricing-data/realtime/

Authorization for Alpaca streams works by sending special authorization messages, not via authorization headers (see docs linked above).